# Judit Polgar is too famous perhaps?

Tags: psychology

It's often said that Judit Polgar can't play with the black pieces. Is this true for any identifiable reason or is it fair to say such commentary is simply jealous sniping.

Comment: Voting to close unless a citation is provided.

Answer (score 10):

> It's often said that Judit Polgar can't play with the black pieces.

I have never heard this.

I just looked her up on MegaBase and her performance rating as White was 2677 and as Black was 2610, which is a pretty normal difference of 67 points. For comparison, Kasparov's performance rating as White was 2809 and as Black was 2725, a difference of 84 points, and Carlsen's performance rating as White has been 2748 and as Black has been 2684, a difference of 64 points.

> Is this true for any identifiable reason

No.

> or is it fair to say such commentary is simply jealous sniping.

I imagine so.